# Does Vertica HCatalog Connector support non-standard Hive's StorageHandler?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, vertica, hcatalog

I'm looking for a way to get HBASE data available/queriable in Vertica. I have seen that Vertica has a good integration with Hive's Metastore - [HCatalog Connector](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/HadoopIntegrationGuide/HCatalogConnector/UsingTheHCatalogConnector.htm%3FTocPath%3DHadoop%2520Integration%2520Guide%7CUsing%2520the%2520HCatalog%2520Connector%7C_____0). 
The connector can read a table definition out of Hive Metastore and use the description to read the data directly.

The question is whether the connector supports the reading of Hive external tables configured with non-standard StorageHandler, HBaseStorageHandler in particular.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this long time ago and I was able to read Hive external tables using the HiveHBaseStorageHandler ( i think the name of the jar is hive-hbase-handler.jar) . Please give it a try and let us know. You need to place this jar in /opt/vertica/packages/hcat/lib/ .